# No adapter attached; skipping layout : RecyclerView (with adapter)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**ListPetientFragment.java**

```
    public class ListPetientFragment extends Fragment {

    private String URLstring = "http://192.168.43.29:8080/emedical/list.php";
    private static ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<DataModel> dataModelArrayList;
    RvAdapter rvAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list,container,false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        fetchingJSON();
        return v;
    }

    private void fetchingJSON() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLstring,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Log.d("strrrrr", ">>" + response);

                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            if(obj.optString("selected").equals("selected")){

                                dataModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                                JSONArray dataArray  = obj.getJSONArray("code1");

                                for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

                                    DataModel playerModel = new DataModel();
                                    JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    playerModel.setNames(dataobj.getString("names"));
                                    playerModel.setPhone(dataobj.getString("phoneNumber"));
                                    playerModel.setDisease(dataobj.getString("disease"));
                                    dataModelArrayList.add(playerModel);
                                }
                                setupRecycler();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        // request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
    private void setupRecycler(){
        rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(getContext(),dataModelArrayList);
        rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    }

}
```

Error is:
2021-11-17 18:41:02.417 29997-29997/? E/rtphonemedicat: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-11-17 18:41:03.628 29997-30029/com.nigoote.smartphonemedicate E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
2021-11-17 18:41:03.698 29997-30029/com.nigoote.smartphonemedicate E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2021-11-17 18:41:13.899 29997-29997/com.nigoote.smartphonemedicate E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't notify dataset before set Adapter to recycleview

```
private void setupRecycler(){
        rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(getContext(),dataModelArrayList);
        rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //remove this line
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    }
```

update this function with

```
private void setupRecycler(){
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(getContext(),dataModelArrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
    
        }
```